# Check only numbers used in input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, input, phone-number

I have a simple if statment in a verify function that check at least 10 numbers are used in a field

```
function verfiyFields() {
    var flag = true;

    var number = $atj('#interested-number-form');


    if(number.val().replace(/\s+/g, '').length < 10){
        number.parent().prepend('<p class="form-error">Please enter phone number</p>');
        fadeOut();
        flag = false;
    }

    return flag;
}
```

How can I also check that only numbers are used.

Comment: If you are using html5, why not just use 'input type = number' attribute for your field?

Comment: I need to be able to put spaces in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `.match(/^\d+$/)` to check if there are only digits.

```
var value = number.val().replace(/\s+/g, '');
if (value.length >= 10 && value.match(/^\d+$/)) {
  // ..
}
```

You can also check if there are at least 10 digits using the regular expression `/^\d{10,}$/` and avoid checking the `length` property:

```
var value = number.val().replace(/\s+/g, '')
if (value.match(/^\d{10,}$/)) {
  // ..
}
```

---

As a side note, you can also use the [`pattern` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation):

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" pattern="^\d{10,}$" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: None of these functions seem to be working for me. I have updated the question with more of the code I'm using

Comment: @ttmt Your title implies that you are trying to check if the field contains *only* digits. Are you just trying to count the number of digits? Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/yacka3zj/ Maybe I am misunderstanding the question..

Comment: It's a phone number field in a form so I want to validate there is at least 10 numbers not counting spaces or other characters that aren't numbers. I only  want numbers and spaces and for there to be at least 10 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
function verfiyFields() {
  var reg = /^\D*(?:\d\D*){10}$/;
  var number = $atj('#interested-number-form');

  var flag = reg.test(number.val())

  if (!(flag)) {
    number.parent().append('<p class="form-error">Please enter a valid 10 digit phone number</p>');
  }

  return flag;
}
```

Use RegExp.test(str) to check to make sure that the length of the field excluding all characters that are not digits is 10. RegExp.test returns a true or false value so this can be the flag you return.

**RegExp.test(str) Documentation**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

***Demo:***
http://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/1v6vnath/